# Looking to change the header from a color to an image

Tags: media

I am using the NewsCenter theme for my Drupal site, and we have had a new logo/banner designed for our website that I want to implement -- but it's not as simple as just uploading it and replacing the old logo.

1. This is the header of our site as it stands currently:
   [image: Current setup]
2. This is what I want to get to:
   [image: Desired outcome]

Also, with the final option, I still need to have users be able to click in the banner and get directed 'Home' -- I presume that to do this I would still upload a logo.png, but that it would just be a large transparent rectangle.

Thanks!

Comment: Update your site logo with the new logo on a transparent background. The background image needs to be set with CSS, which is off topic on this site but can be asked on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I couldn't include a third image -- but basically the entire banner is a single image. It essentially _is_ the logo.  But your post has inspired me to try something -- to take the main text off the background, treat that as the logo, and use the remaining banner as the background image. That still leaves me with the initial question of "Where do I go to change the charcoal gray background of the header to be the violet sunburst image?"

Comment: `to take the main text off the background, treat that as the logo, and use the remaining banner as the background image` That is what I meant. `Where do I go to change the charcoal gray background of the header to be the violet sunburst image?` That is a theme CSS issue and you need to set the background of your header div using CSS. As I stated earlier, it is off-topic as it not specific to Drupal.

Comment: @howard-price I will do the CSS for you over lunch today bro.  I found your site. I need the Reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS:

```
<style>
  #header {
    background: url('critic-banner-image.png');
  }
  #logo {
    margin: 0 15px 5px 15px;
  }
</style>
```

Add this background image 
[image](use better ones that your client provides)

Replace your old logo with this:

[image]

(use better ones that your client provides)

Comment: Hey Howard Prince, I just did all the work for you.  how about an up-vote, or a solved?  ;-)

Comment: Hi! Just got the notice in my email that this message came through. :)  I definitely upvoted it. Marked it as solved, but couldn't get my upvote count to show (as I, too, lack enough reputation points for that to happen).  Thanks! Soon as I get back the graphics that are being reworked, this is exactly what I will do!